# Find multiple html element with exact text and replace it using loop

Tags: html, jquery

I am having trouble to find and replace exact html element. For my code, it will replace all the value at the first condition(y<10). Can anybody point out what went wrong?

```
<table id="grid2" border=1>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>venue_1</th>
        <th>venue_5</th>
        <th>venue_10</th>
        <th>venue_15</th>
        <th>venue_20</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
for(var y=0; y<30; y++){
 if(y < 10){
  $("#grid2 th:contains('venue_"+y+"')").html("less");
 }else if(y>=10 && y<20){
  $("#grid2 th:contains('venue_"+y+"')").html("medium");
 }else{
 $("#grid2 th:contains('venue_"+y+"')").html("more");}}
```

JSFiddle:[here](https://jsfiddle.net/drzwc75o/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `:contains('venue_1')` it will match 1,10,15. `:contains('venue_2')` will match 20.

A better approach is to loop through jQuery collection and match against the number.

```js
$("#grid2 th").each(function() {
  const el = jQuery(this);
  const y = el.text().match(/\d+/)[0];

  if (y < 10) {
    el.text("less");
  } else if (y >= 10 && y < 20) {
    el.text("medium");
  } else {
    el.text("more");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid2" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>venue_1</th>
      <th>venue_5</th>
      <th>venue_10</th>
      <th>venue_15</th>
      <th>venue_20</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: It seems that it returns error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

Comment: It is working fine. Did you copy the code or run it here?

Comment: I copied the code. I run it on company's server where I work from.

Comment: Probably you did not include the library. But if you run it here it works fine.

Comment: I see. I probably can't include the library because of work place server. Is there another alternatives? I can see that some people use .filter() [link](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: The library is jQuery. Nothing else was added. The code depends on it.

Comment: I can see that the jquery library is there with version 1.12.4. I'm not sure whats causing it. Maybe the version is too old. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: That's a very old version. Try to update it. And if you are happy with the answer please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 for(var y=0; y<30; y++){
 if(y < 10){
  $("#grid2 th:contains('venue_"+y+"')").html("less");
 }else if(y>=10 && y<20){
  $("#grid2 th:contains('venue_"+y+"')").html("medium");
 }else{
 $("#grid2 th:contains('venue_"+y+"')").html("more");}}
```

```html
<table id="grid2" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>venue_1</th>
      <th>venue_5</th>
      <th>venue_10</th>
      <th>venue_15</th>
      <th>venue_20</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```